# Sorted/searchable StackedInline options

Tags: python, django

I have three classes:

1. Person
2. Publication
3. AuthorOrder

`Publication` has a m2m field to `Person` [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) `AuthorOrder`. This is done to enable making it possible to set the order of authors, which matters for academic publications.

However, the list of `Person`s is getting long, and it would therefore be nice if it was searchable or at least sorted. However, if I use the obvious method of setting a `Meta` class to `Person`, this causes the `Person`s to be sorted everywhere, including where I don't want them to be.

Is there a way to make it searchable (best) or at least sorted without ruining the order elsewhere (ok)?

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. This works well for us on several projects. https://github.com/and3rson/django-searchable-select